# ARKit 1.5: Extract the recognized image

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, image-recognition

So, my goal is:

- Find known image
- Extract it from the sceneView (e.g take a snapshot)
- Perform further processing

It was quite easy to complete 1st step using **ARReferenceImage** :

```
guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else { return }

let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages
```

But now I can't figure out how to extract the image form the SceneView. I have the plane node added to the imageAnchor:

```
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor
            else { return }

        let planeNode = self.getPlaneNode(withReferenceImage: imageAnchor.referenceImage)
        planeNode.opacity = 0.5
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }
}
```

And the result:
[image]

So that, I need the planeNode's *projection* on the screen to get node's 2D screen coordinates and then cut the image. I found this method: `renderer.projectPoint(node.position)` but it didn't help me. It can even return negative values when the whole picture is on the screen..

Am I doing it the correct way? Any help would be very appreciated
.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it.

```
    let transform = node.simdConvertTransform(node.simdTransform, to: node.parent!)

    let x = transform.columns.3.x
    let y = transform.columns.3.y
    let z = transform.columns.3.z

    let position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
    let projection = renderer.projectPoint(position)

    let screenPoint =  CGPoint(x: CGFloat(projection.x), y: CGFloat( projection.y))
```

For more info

[ARKit 2 - Crop Recognizing Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453203/arkit-2-crop-recognizing-images)

[iOS 8 Core Image saving a section of an Image via Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526787/ios-8-core-image-saving-a-section-of-an-image-via-swift)

https://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2012/03/coreimage-and-uikit-coordinates.html